# What does Third Party SSO login type mean?

Tags: single-sign-on, login

I just got an email to verify my identity with an verification code, but I wasn't trying to log in to salesforce at that moment. I looked at the login history and the attempt was from my IP address and the login type was "Third Party SSO." I don't know what I have set up in the org that would fall under Third Party SSO. What are examples of this? How  can I figure out which third party it was that attempted to log in?

Comment: Are you logging in from community? See this link, if that helps -- https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_security_auth_login_history_types.htm

Comment: No, I'm not logging in from community.